# My app crashes for different screen sizes

Tags: android, crash, size, screen, responsive

i made an android activity for "layout-normal-land-1920x1080" but everytime i try to run it crashes,it only works for the default xml file, but the layout changes for different screen sizes, i want the activity to run with the same UI for all different screen sizes and dimentions , if there is a way to make a responsive android app ??[folders of layout for different screen sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMK9d.png) 
[screenshots for the previews of xml files(yellow buttons)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBh3I.png)

Android Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens= "true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
```

Default xml code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".TicketActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">


<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"  />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50"
    />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt1"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt6"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt11"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt2"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"


    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt7"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt12"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.619" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt3"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt2"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt8"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt13"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt12"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt4"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt9"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt14"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#ffff0f"

    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt13"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt5"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    android:background="#ffff0f"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt10"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    android:background="#ffff0f"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt15"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/butt14"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    android:background="#ffff0f"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/themeTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="15pt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error:

```
Process: com.example.asad.tdk, PID: 3667
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asad.tdk/com.example.asad.tdk.TicketActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001e
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001e
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2101)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1115)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.asad.tdk.TicketActivity.onCreate(TicketActivity.java:76)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: whats logcat throwing.

Comment: Hello Asad and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to add the logcat of the crash metioned

Comment: have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

To maintain your app for different screen resolutions you may have to use multiple layouts or multiple dimens.xml files. 
Basically, we maintain layouts for 

340 X 480 - mdpi

540 X 960 - hdpi

720 X 1280- Xhdpi

1080 X 1920- XXhdpi(1080 X 2160,1080 X 2200 fullview displays)

1440 X 2880- XXXhdpi

6.5 to 7.5 inch tab- sw600dp

7.5-10.1 inch tab-sw720dp

greater than above- sw800dp

if you want to maintain layouts for multiple devices, 
 create xmls for above resolution name i.e, **layout-xxhdpi,layout-xxxhdpi**. For landscape- **layout-land-hdpi**

But android app cannot be responsive in real. you can do other thing like design for 340 X 480 i.e, mdpi. let Android system scale that using DP calculations. This way your UI will be a bit responsive for mobiles.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i have made different layouts for different for differen screensize using the qualifiers but it still doesnt work , when i delete the deafult xml file the app crashes but when i have both it runs the xml file instead of the specific one i made,

Comment: for which resolution device you have created the layout

Comment: i made one for pixel 2 , galaxy nexus, pixel u xl

Comment: layout.xml is the default layout. u keep this layout and create a layout as layout-xxxhdpi and try